# Android Studio strange error when attempting to run emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I don't ever remember having this error. I'm running Android Studio 1.5.1 with JVM 64 and JRE 1.8.0_60 x86_64. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was weird, it seems to be working now. I had to access my SDK tools folder and rename the emulator from 'emulator64-x86' to 'emulator-x86'.